# Mysql GROUP BY in LEFT JOIN and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, left-join

I have this query which works fine

```
    $query = "SELECT 
        beva_post.*, 
        CONVERT_TZ(beva_post.date_published, '-00:00', '+00:00') as moment, 
        beva_rubrique.titre_en, 
        beva_user.image_user   
        FROM beva_post 
        LEFT JOIN beva_user 
            ON beva_user.id_user = beva_post.id_user 
        LEFT JOIN beva_rubrique 
            ON beva_rubrique.id_rubrique = beva_post.id_rubrique 
        LEFT JOIN beva_post_like 
            ON beva_post_like.id_post = beva_post.id_post 
        WHERE beva_post.id_user != '' 
        AND beva_post.flag = 'true' ";
$query .= "ORDER BY beva_post.id_post DESC ";
$query .= "LIMIT 50";
```

But I would like to ORDER this query not by id_post DESC but by id_post that have the most like by id_user (DESC) in the table beva_post_like

The beva_post_like table looks like this :

```
    +-------------+--------------+
    | id_post     | id_user      |
    +-------------+--------------+
    | 1           | 20           |
    | 1           | 11           |
    | 1           | 10           |
    | 2           | 20           |
    | 2           | 50           |
    | 1           | 15           |
    +-------------+--------------+
```

I tried with GROUP BY in the LEFT JOIN beva_post_like but it does not work !

Do I have to use more queries ?

Thanks for your help...

Chris

After your answer I did this but I still have some posts with 'like' at the end

```
    $query = "SELECT 
        beva_post.*, 
        COUNT(beva_post.id_post) as cpt, 
        CONVERT_TZ(beva_post.date_published, '-00:00', '+00:00') as moment, 
        beva_rubrique.titre_en, 
        beva_user.image_user  
        FROM beva_post 
        LEFT JOIN beva_user 
            ON beva_user.id_user = beva_post.id_user 
        LEFT JOIN beva_rubrique 
            ON beva_rubrique.id_rubrique = beva_post.id_rubrique 
        LEFT JOIN beva_post_like 
            ON beva_post_like.id_post = beva_post.id_post 
        WHERE beva_post.id_user != '' 
        AND beva_post.flag = 'true' ";
$query .= "GROUP BY beva_post.id_post ";
$query .= "ORDER BY cpt DESC ";
$query .= "LIMIT 50";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have posts ordered by count of users that liked it?
If it is that case, you can `GROUP BY id_post`, adding a `COUNT(id_user)` in the `SELECT` and ORDER BY DESC on this `COUNT(id_user)`.

If I misunderstand your question, can you be more precise on your ORDER BY goal?

Comment: I need to order the post by those who have the most like by user. The post who do not have any like must also be show but at the end.

Comment: Why did it not work? The `GROUP BY` did not return any results? Can you edit the first post with your new query?

Comment: I posted my query above ;))

Comment: Add this to your SELECT: `COUNT(beva_post_like.id_user) AS 'NB_LIKES'`, and `ORDER BY NB_LIKES DESC`.